# Magento Module Randomly Stopped Working

Tags: php, xml, magento, module, package

I have a Magento Module on Enterprise Edition that I have created , when I initially set it up it was all working, no problems what so ever , now I've come back to it , Magento throws a (404 not found 2) , Before it worked fine, Nothing has changed, Permissions haven't neither has the code, il drop some snippets below but heres some basic package information, the controller doesn't work on the frontend but the backend controller launches with no error.

Package Name/Namespace: Jejamescycles
Module Name: Finance
Codepool: Community
Active: true

The first file - app/code/community/Jejamescycles/Finance/controllers/IndexController.php

```
<?php

    class Jejamescycles_Finance_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action{
        public function indexAction(){

            $conn = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');

            $conn->query("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `v12_finance_sales`
            (
                `sales_id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
                `sales_reference` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE, 
                `customer_id` INT(11) NOT NULL , 
                `products` TEXT NOT NULL , 
                `total_price` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL , 
                `status` VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL , 
                PRIMARY KEY(`sales_id`)
            )");



            $this->loadLayout();

             $block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
                                                'Mage_Core_Block_Template',
                                                'v12content'
                                                )
                                   ->setTemplate('v12_finance/index.phtml');
            $this->getLayout()->getBlock('content')->append($block);

            $this->renderLayout();

        }
        private function _getCustomerSession() {
            Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'frontend'));
            return Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
        }
        function successAction()
        {

            $reference = $_GET['REF'];
            $sales_reference = $_GET['SR'];
            $status = $_GET['Status'];
            $auth = $_GET['Auth'];

            $conn = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core/read');

            $confirmed = 0;

            if($status == 'A' || $status == 'S')
            {
                $confirmed = 1;
            }
            try{

                $conn->query("UPDATE `v12_finance_sales` SET `confirmed` = '$confirmed' , `status` = '$status' WHERE `sales_reference` = '$sales_reference'");

                $this->loadLayout();

                $this->renderLayout();

            }catch(Exception $e)
            {
                $fh = fopen("FINANCE_LOG.log" , "a+");
                fwrite($fh , "ERROR[" . date('H:i:s d-m-Y') . ']:EXCEPTION:' . $e->getMessage());
                fclose($fh);

                $conn->query("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `v12_finance_errors`
                (
                    `error_id` int(11) not null AUTO_INCREMENT, 
                    `sales_reference` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL , 
                    `status` VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL , 
                    PRIMARY KEY(`error_id`)
                )");

                $conn->query("INSERT INTO `v12_finance_errors`
                    (
                        `sales_reference` , 
                        `status`
                    ) VALUES (
                        '" . $sales_reference . "' , 
                        '$status'
                    )");

                die("There was an error processing this request, please contact <a href='mailto:support@jejamescycles.co.uk'>Support</a> with this URL");
            }

        }
        function basic_infoAction()
        {
            $conn = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core/read');

           // $conn->query("ALTER TABLE `v12_finance_sales` ADD COLUMN `status` varchar(4) NOT NULL");
            if(!Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()){
                //not logged in

                header("Location: http://" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . "/customer/account");

            }else{
                 $this->loadLayout();

                 $block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
                                                    'Mage_Core_Block_Template',
                                                    'v12content'
                                                    )
                                       ->setTemplate('v12_finance/finance_setup.phtml');
                $this->getLayout()->getBlock('content')->append($block);

                $this->renderLayout();
            }

        }
}
```

`?>`

And the config.xml file:

```
<config>
<!-- ... -->
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <!-- the <helloworld> tagname appears to be arbitrary, but by
            convention is should match the frontName tag below-->
            <jejamescycles_finance>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Jejamescycles_Finance</module>
                    <frontName>jejamescycles_finance</frontName>
                </args>
            </jejamescycles_finance>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
    <global>
         <helpers>
            <finance>
                <!-- Helper definition needed by Magento -->
                <class>Jejamescycles_Finance_Helper</class>
            </finance>
        </helpers>
        <blocks>
          <jejamescycles_finance>
            <class>Jejamescycles_Finance_Block</class>
          </jejamescycles_finance>
        </blocks>
    </global>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <jejamescycles_finance before="Mage_Adminhtml">Jejamescycles_Finance_Adminhtml</jejamescycles_finance>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
<!-- ... -->
</config>
```

No environment variables have changed , The module itself is independant and doesnt rely on any other packages, I can't figure out for the life of me why it isn't working. I've also checked the CMS Pages and there is no collision of url keys.

Answer (score 0):

I've changed the config.xml to:

```
<config>
<!-- ... -->
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <!-- the <helloworld> tagname appears to be arbitrary, but by
            convention is should match the frontName tag below-->
            <finance>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Jejamescycles_Finance</module>
                    <frontName>finance</frontName>
                </args>
            </finance>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
    <global>
         <helpers>
            <finance>
                <!-- Helper definition needed by Magento -->
                <class>Jejamescycles_Finance_Helper</class>
            </finance>
        </helpers>
        <blocks>
          <jejamescycles_finance>
            <class>Jejamescycles_Finance_Block</class>
          </jejamescycles_finance>
        </blocks>
    </global>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <jejamescycles_finance before="Mage_Adminhtml">Jejamescycles_Finance_Adminhtml</jejamescycles_finance>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
<!-- ... -->
</config>
```

And this has worked, it still baffles me why it hasn't been working though, this was the original config.xml file and did work.